# ROS Answers SE migration: Two left feet?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the drcsim-1.3.1 .dae files, it appears both feet have the same Y dimensions:
relative to 0 0 0 (the joint):
min   -0.0825   -0.0616   -0.0811
max   0.1794    0.0627    0.0105
So each foot is about 1cm wider to the left, relative to the joint.
Let me know if I have interpreted this incorrectly.
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1063/two-left-feet?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[ticketed here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/98/two-left-feet)

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

0.0616m and 0.0627m are 1.1mm different.

---

Originally posted by [RoboUser](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/88/robouser/) with karma: 36 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-01-25**:
I thought the documentation said decameter. That's the metric system for you, so confusing! I remember when we measured feet in feet ...